# Lightweight Javascript for animating div height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webos

I was wondering is there any alternatives to Jquery for animating Div heights in JavaScript? While Jquery is great and relatively small, I dont want to load the entire jquery just for this one functionality. And considering this is for a WebOs app (not a web app), I need to keep the loading time as small as possible.

Thanks

Comment: What animations are you looking for?

Comment: animate height from 0 to 100px or vise versa within a specified amount of time.

Comment: As a note, [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) is a lightweight alternative for jQuery targetted at Webkit phones.  It uses `-webkit-transition` for its animations though, so that's not a lot of help if you want a scripted solution.

Comment: Just use CSS3 Transitions, if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function animateHeight(obj, height){

   var obj_height = obj.clientHeight;

   if(obj_height <= height){ return; }
   else {
       obj.style.height = (obj_height - 5) + "px";
       setTimeout(function(){
           animateHeight(obj, height);
       }, 500) 
   }
}
```

Nice fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Z6cbq/

Answer (score 2):

WebOS uses mobile WebKit, so you could do most of the work with CSS:

```
#someElement {
    -webkit-transition: height 100ms linear;
    height: 0;
}
```

Then your JavaScript is really easy:

```
document.querySelector('#someElement').style.height = '100px'
// - or -
document.querySelector('#someElement').className += ' open';
// where #someElement.open has a defined height.
```

Here's some more details: http://pre101.com/blog/2009/11/10/a-guide-to-css-transitions-in-webos/

Comment: I have been using CSS animations, but it seems JS runs alot smoother on the Touchpad than CSS animations.

Comment: That's weird, a touchpad and not a touchpad emulator?  CSS animations should always be smoother.  Are you doing something where the flow has to get calculated a lot?  Maybe you could try `-webkit-transform: scaleY(...)`

Comment: Interesting. what is the syntax for using that? (assuming the div by default is at 0px height)

Comment: Its decimals like opacity.  Normal would be `scaleY(1)`.  This should get the GPU involved too for improved performance.  The caveat is that this doesn't affect page flow.  You can try it on this page with `$('pre').css({'-webkit-transition': 'all 1s linear', '-webkit-transform': 'scaleY(0)'})`

Comment: Well I tried that, but its not behaving as I need it to. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

A bare bones animation library weighing in at `1 KB`:

https://github.com/relay/anim/